# In eclipse, what are the numbers in brackets beside files checked out from svn?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I have several java projects checked out from svn which I view through eclipse (Version: Kepler Service Release 2 Build id: 20140224-0627). The svn information is displayed to the right of the project name (and alongside each individual file).

Some projects also have a number in brackets alongside (to the right of) the svn information (and so do some files within that project - the number beside the project being the sum of those beside the individual files)

Intuitively I want to say the numbers represent server side changes that I need to bring down to my local workspace but they don't change or disappear if I do an svn update.

Does anyone know what they mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may not be SVN information, any plugins can add a 'label decoration'.

Look in 'Preferences > General > Appearance > Label Decorations' to see the enabled decorations.

Look in 'Preferences > Team > SVN > Label Decorations' to see the exact format of SVN label decorations.